# Transaction based operations in kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I'm working with a `org.apache.kafka 3.3.1` streams and I kind of need to do a transaction like operation - I'm trying to remap incoming event and save it into two output topics. In this case `split/branch` doesn't work, because as I understand from documentation it will end up in a first `branch` where predicate is `true`.

Code below does what I want to achieve, but how can I make sure that if any exception or network issue happens in both topics nothing will be saved at all like in transaction based operations - "all or nothing".

```
    KStream<String, InputObj> stream = builder.stream("input-topic", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), InputObj.serdes));
    stream.map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(key, OutputObj1::new)).to("output-topic1" , Produced.with(Serdes.String(), OutputObj1.serdes);
    stream.map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(key, OutputObj2::new)).to("output-topic2" , Produced.with(Serdes.String(), OutputObj2.serdes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be guaranteed by exactly-once semantics, enabled by setting `processing.guarantee` to `exactly_once_v2`. See

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html

The two sinks `output-topic1` and `output-topic2` will be part of the same sub-topology, which looks something like this:

```
Topologies:
   Sub-topology: 0
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000 (topics: [input-topic])
      --> KSTREAM-MAP-0000000001, KSTREAM-MAP-0000000003
    Processor: KSTREAM-MAP-0000000001 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000002
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000
    Processor: KSTREAM-MAP-0000000003 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000004
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000
    Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000002 (topic: output-topic1)
      <-- KSTREAM-MAP-0000000001
    Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000004 (topic: output-topic2)
      <-- KSTREAM-MAP-0000000003
```

For this sub-topology you will get one streams task for each partition of `input-topic`. The task is atomic, in the sense that it will not be further broken down - with exactly once processing enabled, the output records for the two output topics will be committed as part of the same transaction, so you are guaranteed to have a consistent view of the two topics in downstream clients, as long as you consume with `isolation.level` being set to `read.committed`.

Comment: lets say I can't know who/how will read my output topics, does it mean that if consumer will not change his default of "isolation.level" which is "read_uncommitted" by documentation, then there is no point of using exactly_once_v2 and then this doesn't work? BTW I appreciate your response, thanks.

Comment: "To read transactions cleanly (i.e., ignore in-flight and aborted transactions), we will set the consumer isolation level to read_committed." from the book "Kafka: The Definitive guide".

Comment: Yes. An EOS streams application will atomically write a commit marker to the output topics when a transaction committed. A `read_uncomitted` client will read all records in the output topic, a `read_comitted` client will ignore all records that don't have a commit marker.